# .net 6 NLog log different namespaces to different log files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, nlog

I would like to log all events with this namespace: Microsoft.Extensions.* in one log file and all the other events in a different log file.

My nlog config file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Define targets -->
    <targets>
        <!-- Target for Microsoft.Extensions.* namespaces -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="MicrosoftExtensionsLog" fileName="logs/MicrosoftExtensions.log"
                layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}${exception:format=tostring}" />

        <!-- Target for other namespaces -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="OtherLog" fileName="logs/Other.log"
                layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}${exception:format=tostring}" />
    </targets>

    <!-- Define rules -->
    <rules>
        <!-- Log Microsoft.Extensions.* namespaces to MicrosoftExtensionsLog -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.Extensions.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="MicrosoftExtensionsLog" final="true" />

        <!-- Log everything else to OtherLog -->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="OtherLog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

With the above config file the Microsoft.Extensions.* logs are still being put in the 'OtherLog' file.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm guessing that the unexpected Logger-output, comes from a Logger with name that doesn't match `name="Microsoft.Extensions.*"`. Can you update the target-Layout to include `${logger}` ? You can also try to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging) with `internalLogLevel="Debug"` and verify expected target for Loggers. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: I tried your configuration in NET 6 application and found that it works correctly. But in the Other.log file  a lot of logs from Microsoft.Hosting.* and Microsoft.AspNetCore.* loggers appear. Perhaps you should use `name="Microsoft.*"` instead of `name="Microsoft.Extensions.*"`.